# Access another module.exports function from the same file node.js

Tags: node.js, module

To make it a bit more clear to what I'm trying to achieve.

I have a server running which includes many module, and one of the module use to check if the user role is an admin or not.

in `Server.js`

```
   var loginAPI = require('myModule')(argStringType),
       express = require('express');

   var app = express();
```

Now that in the `myModule.js` I have few functions that already been implemented and just wanted to add one more, but this function really doesn't need to be call from the `server.js` instead it will be call once the person visit the `URL`, so I want to add something like this to the `myModule.js`

in `myModule.js`

```
app.get( "/post/:postid", function( req, res ) {
  var id = req.param('postid');
  return getContent( postid );
});



// Module.exports
module.exports = function ( arg ) {

  return {

    getContent: function ( id ) { },

    getHeader: function ( id ) { };
};
```

So as you can see from the above, I have two function which is in the `module.exports` and they worked fine no problem except the one which is outside the `module.exports` that one work if I don't try to call the `getContent`, but that is what I'm trying to achieve. When someone visit the site by entering the `URL` in that format the `app.get` should be fire and do whatever is implemented to do.

Comment: Couldn't you just export it as well? I don't see the point of the question otherwise. `return { exportName: exportName, [...]` and after require: `loginAPI.exportName(arg)`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté The thing is that I want this `app.get` to always be active without being call, so once they do the `require` it will be use right away.

Comment: I see. Still not entirely sure of what you're trying to achieve, but from your code seems like you'd like to add a method to the `global` object.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I'm so sorry with my question is very confuse I know that, but here is a briefly explaination of what I'm trying to achieve. We have a server that include a lot of the module and one of the module that I'm trying to implement got some functionality, and so I want to add one more function into it, but the problem is that this function needs to be always active meaning that it doesn't need to be call only when they visited that `URL` then it will be active. When they visited that site they have to access the other function to get some detail as well.

Comment: I second what Fabrício said, if you're wanting to use `exportName`, why not export it? `module.exports.exportName = function (arg) {...};` and then call it by using `loginAPI.exportName(arg);`. If that's not what you're asking, you might need to rework your question with expanded descriptions and examples.

Comment: I will edit my question to make it more clear @BretCopeland

Comment: @BretCopeland I have edited my question to make it more clear, and I hope that is a bit better.

Comment: That does make more sense, but you're `module.exports` function returns a closure, and in order to call a method in that closure, you need access to it in the form of a reference (in other words, the variable you've named `loginAPI`). Without access to that variable, your app.get handler will never be able to call `getContent`, since, when you think about it, there could be zero or a million instantiations of `getContent` depending on how many times `module.exports()` was called. How would it know which one to call?

Comment: @BretCopeland Well think about it this way, when we include the `require('myModule)` it's like I have the code included in my `server.js` just the part of the `module.exports` won't be call automatically unless I have to invoke it, but the part of the `app.get` it will always be there and get calls when people enter the `URL` right?

Comment: I think maybe you aren't quite understanding how `require` works. It is calling `require('moduleB')` inside moduleA is __not__ equivalent to placing moduleB's code inside moduleA because the scopes are different. From the looks of it, you're trying to use the `app` variable inside `myModule` where it doesn't even exist. Here, I'll just post an answer to illustrate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you realize each module in Node.js has its own scope. So

ModuleA:

```
var test = "Test output string";
require('ModuleB');
```

ModuleB:

```
console.log(test);
```

Will simply output `undefined`.

With that said, I think this is the style of module you're looking for:

server.js:

```
var app = //instantiate express in whatever way you'd like
var loginApi = require('loginModule.js')(app);
```

loginModule.js:

```
module.exports = function (app) {

  //setup get handler
  app.get( "/post/:postid", function( req, res ) {
    var id = req.param('postid');
    return getContent( postid );
  });

  //other methods which are indended to be called more than once
  //any of these functions can be called from the get handler
  function getContent ( id ) { ... }

  function getHeader ( id ) { ... }

  //return a closure which exposes certain methods publicly
  //to allow them to be called from the loginApi variable
  return { getContent: getContent, getHeader: getHeader };
};
```

Obviously, adjust to fit your actual needs. There are lots of ways to do the same type of thing, but this fits closest with your original example. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: It make more sense from your answer and I do understand it better in your way, but the only problem I have and concern about is that I don't want to modify the whole module that I'm trying to implement. It is an open source project that I'm contributing to, so they only want me to add something into it, but not changing their codes. Anyway, if it's not possible that way I will try and see if I can use yours and implement it, or maybe ask them if they are okay for me to change their codes. Thanks!

Comment: If it's an open source project, then I would definitely pose your question directly to the maintainers/community and see how they would like it handled. They may very well already have a paradigm in place which would work for you. Good luck.